# Identity File not working

Tags: macos, ssh

Here's what's going on: I have a DSA ssh-key set up on my MacBook Pro, and the `id_dsa.pub` file has been placed in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Permissions are 600 for `id_dsa`.

I'm still being asked for my password, what do I do?

I've included output from level 1 debugging below, which I believe should have sufficient information to identify the problem. If not let me know and I will provide level 3.

```
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:.ssh dsmith$ ssh -v km4ayu.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/dsmith/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/dsmith/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for km4ayu.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to km4ayu.com [104.168.167.30] port 17785.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/dsmith/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dsmith/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to km4ayu.com:17785 as 'kv4lq'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:/214EQvH59cIt2nCaT+XhRruKws4j7Jwo3anBGMGO6g
debug1: Host '[km4ayu.com]:17785' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/dsmith/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /Users/dsmith/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: password
kv4lq@km4ayu.com's password:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new openssh version (7.0+) **deprecated DSA keys** and is not using DSA keys by default (not on server or client). The keys are not preferred to be used anymore, so if you can, I would recommend to **use RSA keys** where possible.

If you really need to use DSA keys, you need to explicitly allow them in your client config using

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss
```

Should be enough to put that line in `~/.ssh/config`, as the verbose message is trying to tell you. [Ref.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247612/ssh-keeps-skipping-my-pubkey-and-asking-for-a-password/247614#247614)

Comment: `+ssh-dss` or `+ssh-dsa`?